# Bootstrap создать диалог примерно как в соц. сетях

Tags: html, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать диалог примерно как в соц-сетях, хотелось бы вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но максимум, что у меня получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне правильно разместить элементы и какие дать им классы, чтобы получилось как на первом скрине?
Моя неудачная попытка:

```
<ul class="list-group card shadow">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " href="#">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <img src="#" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" alt="Аватар" height="70", width="70">
                <h5 style="" class="mb-1">Никита Хмель</h5>
                <span class="border border-warning text-warning p-1">Не отвечено</span>
            </div>
            <p>Прикреплен файл</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо убрать ненужный row, добавить пару блоков-обёрток и несколько служебных классов:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="list-group card shadow">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " href="#">
      <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <div class="ava-wrap d-flex align-items-center">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1873964/56d28094-012a-491a-96af-42e5aea26b2c/s1200?webp=false" class="rounded-circle img-fluid mr-3" alt="Аватар" height="70" width="70">
          <div class="info-wrap">
            <h5 style="" class="mb-1">Никита Хмель</h5>
            <p class="m-0">Прикреплен файл</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="border border-warning text-warning p-1 align-self-start">Не отвечено</span>
      </div>
    </a>
</ul>
```